# How can I create two identical aliases in bash?

Tags: bash, shell-script, bash-alias

I want to create two different aliases to the same command without repeating myself. How can I do it in bash? For example, I want listlong and longlist to both be aliases to "ls -al".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
alias {listlong,longlist}="ls -al"
```

That should do it.

Answer (score 5):

```
alias listlong='ls -al'
alias longlist=listlong
```

And further changes of the alias `listlong` reflect on `longlist` too.

Comment: I prefer this method because it requires less understanding of bash :-)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a variation on cYrus's answer with even less repetition:

```
alias listlong='ls -al' longlist=listlong
```

If you want to do something similar but have them be independent:

```
cmd='ls -al'; alias listlong=$cmd longlist=$cmd
```

which has similar results to Janne Pikkarainen's answer (which is the least repetitive so far).